# Not able to connect Raspberry to laptop

Tags: networking, ssh, ethernet

I'm trying to connect my laptop to my Raspberry PI with just a LAN cable and without a router because I don't have one. So I just configured a static IP in both the devices and tried to setup a network between them. It appears that the network has been established but when I try to ping (to check whether they are able to communicate or not) my Windows laptop from the Raspberry PI then it is not able to ping but when I ping my Raspberry PI from laptop it pings successfully. My real problem is actually that I am not able to ssh from the laptop to the Raspberry PI through ethernet. The description about pinging I gave just because I thought it will be related to same problem because of which I cannot ssh from laptop to the Raspberry PI, and that the ping description may help you to find the solution to my problem.

Please help me to fix my problem, and be able to access my Raspberry from my laptop.

What kind of additional network detail and configuration should I provide you for the help?

Comment: This is really hard for some versions of Windows as Windows can fail an  Ethernet network but not make that obvious to the user.  That is, the connection may appear to be working but it is not.  Also, you may need a cross over cable if not using a switch.  In the end, routing problems can be difficult to solve.  Especially in your case where you are not providing the responses to many common networking commands such as ifconfig, ipconfig, and route.

Comment: As @st2000 points out you have given no details of the network set up on the Pi or the PC.  How do you expect to get help?

Comment: When there is no router or DHCP server, the Raspberry Pi will try to establish connection vi `link-local` addresses. There is generally no need to set an IP address for `link-local` connections.  IPv4 `link-local` address space is the `169.254.0.0/16` subnet.

Comment: so tell me what kind of network detAil should i provide you

Comment: Well, you could start by explaining *what happens when you try* to establish that SSH connection.

Answer (score 0):

When the ping is working downhill, the network HW and cabling is OK.

No uphill ping response may indicate that your windows machine does not reply to ping and/or that the windows firewall is blocking ping at all.

Regarding the ssh issue - are you sure your ssh server is running?

```
sudo systemctl enable ssh
sudo systemctl start ssh
```

Are you sure your firewall is permitting ssh packets (port 22) to enter the machine? Maybe you could disable your firewall at all for a while.

```
sudo systemctl stop ufw
sudo systemctl stop gufw
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the idea whether the problem is related to the `Public` vs `Private` categorization of your LAN Ethernet network within Windows: some features are configured differently for these. Mine for example, when used without a router on it, typically gets categorized as `Public`.

On Windows, open Powershell with administrator rights, and issue the following:

```sh
Get-NetConnectionProfile
```

This will show you - among other things - the `NetworkCategory`; if it's not `Private`, it needs updating.

The above command will also reveal the `Name` of the Ethernet network. Use that in the following command to set it to `Private`:

```sh
Set-NetConnectionProfile -Name "the value of 'Name' from the previous command" -NetworkCategory Private
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are linking two Ethernet network connections on *Host* devices with a RJ45 twisted pair cable it MUST be a "cross-over" cable, so that the pair of wires that are outputs on one device are connected to the input ones on the other.  As it happens, modern-day switches/routers/hubs can generally automatically swap the pairs of wires over as required, but in the past when they did not have that functionality there was often just one port that had a mechanical switch that did this manually and that port was reserved as a "uplink" port so that it could be wired to *another* switch or hub - so that one did not need a "cross-over" cable.

Anyhow neither a Laptop or a RPi has that reversal so it must be done in the cable before you can get them talking to each other.

Comment: when the ping is working (at leas one-way), the wiring is ok

Comment: At least in *that* direction - I suppose we should not totally rule out a duff network lead - but swapping the connected ends in the situation that the OP describes will confirm it is such a faulty cable if the working ping changes to the other direction...! 8-P

Comment: when at least one way of ping works the cabling is ok, no need to swap cables

Comment: I ***was*** going to suggest you were missing my point that if there is damage to one pair of wires in the lead (in an RJ45 network cable used purely for Ethernet {but NOT PoE} only four of the eight cores are actually used, as two differential pairs, one in each direction) then there could still be data flow in **one** direction but not the other - so unplugging the lead and reconnecting it the other way around will swap the send and receive wires over. However having research the `ping` utility I now realise it does require (and thus test) data flow in both directions after all! 8-O

Comment: I realize this question is long dead, but the Ethernet ports on the Raspberry Pi are auto-sensing, at least for recent models, so a crossover cable is not needed.

Comment: Not entirely dead - and it is useful to know about the auto-sensing, my main switch unit (a Netgear 24-pot 10/100/1000 SmartSwitch GS724T)  has this and calls it "auto-uplink" but Wikipedia gives the more normal term of **[Auto MDI-X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-dependent_interface#Auto_MDI-X)** - interestingly it is only of significance to 10/100 connections as the GigaBit one use ALL 4 pairs of wires and that works out for itself how things are wired up...

Comment: For auto-sensing it is only needed that ONE device can do it and the Raspberry Pi can do it. So a crossover cable is NOT needed. Needing crossover is a legend from the last century.

Comment: That's ageist! Some of us **do** come from the last century... 8-P